# Fastest Way to ExtractNumeric Coding

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of tokens that I want to convert into Numeric Coding for efficiency, I decided to create a dictionary with all the terms and a corresponding code. My questions is, how can I extract the term name corresponding to each term code quickly without have to scan the entire dictionary? Or is there a better way to store the mappings aside from using a dictionary?

```
dict = {
 'imperia': 995,
 'extra': 996,
 'pleated': 997,
 'cake': 998
}
```

I know that I can use the following (but it's slow):

```
return([x for x,y in dict .items() if y == b])
```

Comment: Are the values of the dictionary unique? If so you could create and inverted dictionary. Where the values are the keys and the keys are the values.

Comment: @DanielMesejo yes they are, interesting idea. I will try it out.

Comment: if you need to get something quick from the dictionary you should make the key that item since looking up keys is O(1)